# Placeholder in DT::dataTable search bar

Tags: r, dt, shinyjs, shiny-reactivity

I need some help to something I thought will be easy.

I have a `DT::dataTable` and I like to just put a placeholder in the search bar but I can't see where the option for this is.

Comment: Can you please describe a little more what you wish to do, even with code not working, but something we may bite on with sample data, working code hardcoded and 'pseudo code' describing what you want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using *iris* dataset:

```
library(DT)

DT::datatable(iris, 
              options = list(
                language = list(searchPlaceholder = "setosa")))
```

[image]

Comment: Or: `options = list(language = list(searchPlaceholder = "foo"))`

Comment: @PoGibas yes, that is the correct option, feel free to post as new answer, or edit mine. Thanks.